# How to create Lost found/target in sequence diagram in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sequence-diagram

When we generate sequence diagram using the code in VS2010, the generated diagram normally has a found target defined.
I would like to add a lost target in the diagram.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution...
In my case, it worked when I created asynchronous message.